# Does the Difficulty affect mob equipment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the difficulty level affect mob equimpent? For example, if I select the Hard difficulty, will more of the zombies and skeletons wear armour, than those on Easy? (Or if I spend lots of time on a chunk, to increase local difficulty?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, increased difficulty **does** increase the chance for mobs to have armor, weapons and enchantments. As shown in a graph on the [Difficulty](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Effects_which_increase_in_response_to_various_difficulty_conditions) section of the wiki, mob armor does depend on difficulty.